# A simpler i18n for Python/Django

Tags: python, django, internationalization

My question is regarding i18n in Python. From what I understand, it involves:

- Create a messages file per language (ONLY ONE?!).
- in  this file, each message will be of the format

  - `English message here`
  - `Message en Francais ici` (yea crappy french..)
- then have this file compiled into another faster binary format
- repeat for all other langs needed
- in app code (`Django`) use the translate method with english (or default) language which will be translated correctly based on locale... `tr('English message Here')`

Probably I'm a bit off on the steps, but this seems to be the general sense right?

What I'm wondering is, is there a simpler way? I mean in the java webapp world, you set up message bundle files in the `bundleName_locale.properties` format. In each one you usually have a key to message relation like `greeting = Hello World.` You can have lots of different properties files for different sub sections of your site/app. All the locale files are hierarchical, and missing keys in a sub locale fall through to the parent etc. This is all done automatically by Java, no setup required.

Is there anything like this in the Django/Python world? Is this just insane to follow this route? Could I fake this using a module as a stand in for a java .properties file? Sorry for the long-winded question, and thanks for any input.

Comment: "here is the real issue".  Please delete everything else.  It's confusing.

Comment: will do, I figured it might be

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While you could do this fairly simply, I would question why.

As is:

1. Django's i18n is based around `gettext`, which has never given me any performance problems.
2. You don't have to create the message file, Django will [do it for you](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/localization/#how-to-create-language-files).
3. The messages files Django creates can be sent as a text file to just about anyone for translation.

   - I spent about 5 minutes explaining to someone how to use them, and a day later got back a fantastic translation of my entire site.
4. Marking the strings in your code is very simple.

   - `_("My String")` is normal for `.py` files by using `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _`.
   - `{% trans "My String" %}` in your templates.  Again, quite simple.
   - Writing out `bundle.getString("My String")` seems like it would get old, quick.
5. You can easily incorporate Django's [i18n into your JavaScript](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#specifying-translation-strings-in-javascript-code), if needed.
6. There are [web-based editors](http://code.google.com/p/django-rosetta/) for the message files.
7. You don't have to define a string more than once, it conglomerates all instances into one token across your entire app.

   - How many times do you have to define "Save" in your Java properties files?
8. Still in a nice, version-tracking friendly, text file.
9. If you hack together a `.properties`-like way to define your strings, you'd still want to compile them so that you don't have to parse the text file at execution time.

Example of empty `.po` file:

```
#: templates/inquiries/settings/new_field.html:12
#: templates/inquiries/settings/new_form.html:4
msgid "Save"
msgstr ""
```

Personally, I don't see a reason to bother hacking together a replacement for a solution which already exists and works well.

Comment: Ok this is very helpful stuff... A couple of questions: One of the things i noticed was that there was no equivalence for the java style message format. For instance {0, date, yyyy-MM-dd} or {1, choice, 0#blahs|1#blah|2#blahs|3#blahsess} etc.. but this may be my lack of knowledge. Second, can you have a file for FRENCH_CANADA, that has only differences from FRENCH. And can you have like en_US_tx for "special" cases? Lastly, do you find it manageable to have all translations in a single file. Does this not grow to be too large at some point? Thanks for the great answer though.

Comment: For the date format, you can certainly run this through the translation.  You just translate the date format string in your `settings.py`.  For the choices, you would translate the individual choices, not all at once.  You can define your own language codes, and the Django _should_ handle them fine.  As for the differences, I don't believe so.  But it should be easy enough to do with version control, no?  The file for my site is ~500 strings.  Absolutely manageable.

Comment: You can have "fr_CA" for french canadian, and "fr" for general french. I can see of no reason for it all to be in one big file to be a problem. Considering that the massive book 'War and Peace', is 3MB big, if you have 3 times as much text as that in your programme, it'll still be only 10MB. Quite reasonable.